# if one html tag matches then another tag should be crawled using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html, web-crawler, html-agility-pack, atag

`<a class="product-name" href="http:xyz" title="Polac pineapple slices 3kg">Polac pineapple slices 3kg</a>
<div class="price-box">
<span class="regular-price" id="product-price-5489">
<span class="price">Rs 665</span> </span>`

I want to get the price from the Span tag, but it should provide price of particular item when matched. like if a tag have inner text as Polac pineapple then it should return Rs 665
Following is code i'm using

```
 ` 
var aTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");
                var nextTags  = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span");
if (aTags != null)
                {
                    foreach (var aTag in aTags)
                    {
                        s += counter + ".  " + aTag.InnerText + "<br>";
                        //s += aTag.InnerText;
                        if (aTag.InnerText == "Polac pineapple")
                        {
                            brandcheck = true;
                            find += aTag.InnerText + " ";

                            foreach (var nextTag in nextTags)
                            {
                                //s += counter + ".  " + nextTag.InnerText + "<br>";
                                s += nextTag.InnerText;
                                if (nextTag.InnerText.Contains("Rs"))
                                {
                                    brandcheck = true;
                                    find = nextTag.InnerText + " ";
                                }
                            }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more precise?

You can use "id".

```
<span id="thisspan">A uniquely identifiable element.</span>
```

The id attribute provides a unique identifier for an element within the document. It may be used by an a element to create a hyperlink to this particular element.

The most important aspect of the id attribute is that it must be absolutely unique. Unlike the class attribute, which may apply the same value to many elements in a page, an id that’s applied to an element must not match an id used anywhere else on the same page.

The id attribute value must begin with a letter in the roman alphabet (a–z or A–Z); this can be followed by any combination of letters (a–z or A–Z), digits (0–9), hyphens (-), underscores (_), colons (:), and periods (.). The id value is case sensitive, thus This is me and This is me would be considered to be separate and uniquely identifiable elements on the same web page.

Comment: I'm thankful for your reply..
actually there are multiple of span with same id :/  like <span class="price">